# Search query multiple column with OR and AND to apply filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, search, conditional-statements, where-clause

I working on an app. I trying to implant a search system. Method is simple. On home i search a query on 3 column "name" OR "nomdep" OR "nomregion". After this, I wnat to filter by params with AND operator.

If I implant search with only one column for example "NAME" that's work, i can apply filters. But if i want to implant this with more than one OR I cant apply filter. I think OR operator is the problem. But for sure i have no idea to solve this...

Can you help me ? Thanks

camping.rb

```
has_many :caracteristiquetests, :foreign_key => :camping_id
has_many :situations, :foreign_key => :camping_id

    def self.searchi(query, handicap, animaux, television, plage, etang, lac)
       return scoped unless query.present?
       left_outer_joins(:caracteristiquetests, :situations).where(['nomdep LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR nomregion LIKE ? AND handicap LIKE ? AND animaux LIKE ? AND television LIKE ? AND plage LIKE ? AND etang LIKE ? AND lac LIKE ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{handicap}%", "%#{animaux}%", "%#{television}%", "%#{plage}%", "%#{etang}%", "%#{lac}%"])
    end
```

camping_controller.rb

```
      def resultnohome
        if params[:query].blank?
          redirect_to action: :index and return
        else
          @campings = Camping.searchi(params[:query], params[:handicap], params[:animaux], params[:television], params[:plage], params[:etang], params[:lac])
        end
end
```

caracteristiquetest.rb

```
belongs_to :camping
```

situation.rb

```
belongs_to :camping
```

### EDIT

I edited my model to add "()"

camping.rb

```
def self.searchi(query, handicap, animaux, television, plage, etang, lac)
   return scoped unless query.present?
   left_outer_joins(:caracteristiquetests, :situations).where(['(nomdep LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR nomregion LIKE ?) AND handicap LIKE ? AND animaux LIKE ? AND television LIKE ? AND plage LIKE ? AND etang LIKE ? AND lac LIKE ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{handicap}%", "%#{animaux}%", "%#{television}%", "%#{plage}%", "%#{etang}%", "%#{lac}%"])
end
```

Unfornutualy, I m getting unexpected results : only one result is display, the first match like "Short circuit evaluation". Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use parentheses around the `or` conditions, the result of the `or` conditions will then be combined with the `and` conditions.

```
left_outer_joins(:caracteristiquetests, :situations).where(['(nomdep LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR nomregion LIKE ?) AND handicap LIKE ? AND animaux LIKE ? AND television LIKE ? AND plage LIKE ? AND etang LIKE ? AND lac LIKE ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{handicap}%", "%#{animaux}%", "%#{television}%", "%#{plage}%", "%#{etang}%", "%#{lac}%"])
```

Alternatively, you can split it up into separate `where` statements, which will combine to make one SQL call when you retrieve the results. This would be easier to read and maintain, and doesn't do any calls where a value wasn't provided.

```
result = left_outer_joins(:caracteristiquetests, :situations).where('nomdep LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR nomregion LIKE ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
result = result.where('handicap LIKE ?', "%#{handicap}%") if handicap
result = result.where('animaux LIKE ?', "%#{animaux}%") if animaux
result = result.where('television LIKE ?', "%#{television}%") if television
result = result.where('plage LIKE ?', "%#{plage}%") if plage
result = result.where('etang LIKE ?', "%#{etang}%") if etange
result = result.where('lac LIKE ?', "%#{lac}%") if lac
return result
```

Comment: Unfornutualy I have a same problem. The query doesnt work with filter....

Comment: So what do you mean "can't apply filter" ... are you getting an error or are you getting unexpected results or what?

Comment: When I add my query like this http://localhost:3000/resultnohome?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=alsace only one result is found. But normaly more 100 results match with this query. If i apply filters http://localhost:3000/resultnohome?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=alsace&handicap=oui Same result only one... The first. For your information Alsace is a french region (nomregion)

Comment: This is really strange... It's like a stop when he hit the first result, I doesn't display all results, only the first match. What do you think about this ?

Comment: Could you please show your updated `left_outer_joins` ?

Comment: for sure, I edited my ask with this new update. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Ok, maybe try a multiple-line alternative, which will be easier to read and easier to maintain, and we can do `.count` at each step to see which `where` clause is causing the issue.  I've edited my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks you so much @SteveTurczyn !! All works perfectly. If I could i will put you + 100000 :)

Comment: I have another question like this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069232/ignore-uppercase-downcase-and-accent-in-search :)