# Ignore uppercase, downcase and accent in search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, parameters

I have a search system with filter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691497/search-query-multiple-column-with-or-and-and-to-apply-filter). This system work like a charm but I have some problem with downcase / uppercase and accent.

For example if I search "marée" I have result but if I search "MAREE" or "Marée" or "maree". I don't have result.

I want to fix that. How I can fix this ? Thank you.

my controller

```
    def resultnohome
          if params[:query].blank?
            redirect_to action: :index and return
          else
          @campings = Camping.searchi(params[:query], params[:handicap], params[:animaux], params[:television], params[:plage], params[:etang], params[:lac])
            if params[:query] == "aube"
              @pub = Camping.find_by_id(1)
            else
            end
        end
end
```

My model

```
 def self.searchi(query, handicap, animaux, television, plage, etang, lac)
    return scoped unless query.present?
         result = left_outer_joins(:caracteristiquetests, :situations).where('nomdep LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR nomregion LIKE ? OR commune LIKE?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
         result = result.where('handicap LIKE ?', "%#{handicap}%") if handicap
         result = result.where('animaux LIKE ?', "%#{animaux}%") if animaux
         result = result.where('television LIKE ?', "%#{television}%") if television
         result = result.where('plage LIKE ?', "%#{plage}%") if plage
         result = result.where('etang LIKE ?', "%#{etang}%") if etang
         result = result.where('lac LIKE ?', "%#{lac}%") if lac
      return result
  end
```

Comment: Depends entirely on which database you are using. Postgres has a `ILIKE` keyword that will perform a case insensitive search. In MYSQL you use the lower function `WHERE "foo" LIKE %LOWER("Bar")%`.

Comment: @max  I use SQLite for the moment. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Don't use SQLite, its a toy database. Focus on what DB you are going to be using later in production. I would go with Postgres

Comment: I would go with Mysql I think. But for the moment in production do you have any idea for my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using SQLite then you don't have many good options. The most common suggestion is to have extra columns in your database, that are normalized values so if your `plage` column contains "Marée" then you also have a column `plage_ascii` that contains "maree"

you need to create the additional columns with migrations, then you would have a `before_save` action in your model...

```
before_save :create_normalized_strings

def create_normalized_strings
  self.handicap_ascii = handicap.downcase.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^x00-\x7F]/n, '').to_s
  self.animaux_ascii = animaux.downcase.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^x00-\x7F]/n, '').to_s
  # etc etc
end
```

Then in your search do...

```
if handicap
  test_handicap = handicap.downcase.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^x00-\x7F]/n, '').to_s
  result = result.where('handicap_ascii LIKE ?', "%#{handicap}%")
end
```

It's not great, as it basically forces you to duplicate data in your database into extra columns.  If you can consider more sophisticated databases other than SQLite then you'd be better off... personally I wouldn't ever use SQLite in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks for this reply :) For sure another column is not great :S What is the best way for you ? MySQL ? Postgres ? If I change, what is the method to solve my problem with another Database ?

Comment: I really like PostgreSQL.  It has the capability configure an "unaccent" method, so you can do...  `result = result.where('unaccent(handicap) LIKE unaccent(?)', "%#{handicap}%")`   If the database has 'Hôtel' you can search with 'hotel' and it matches.

Comment: Great ! That's exactly what I need. I'll ask Google to change my sqlite for PostgreSQL in rails ;)